# How to fix 'Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.' in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

Hello from school im making some query's. now i made a query that gets the splits the rating in: very bad, unsufficient, sufficent and very good. now im calcuting how much percent each category is in the rating with the following code:

```
SELECT format(klasse, count(klasse) * 100 / (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM (
                SELECT year(boekingsdatum) AS jaar
                    ,iif(rating IS NULL, 'Geen rating', iif(rating <= 3, 'Zwaar onvoldoende', iif(rating <= 5, 'Onvoldoende', iif(rating < 8, 'Voldoende', 'Zeer goed')))) AS Klasse
                FROM boeking b
                ) AS percentage
            ), 'p')
FROM (
    SELECT year(boekingsdatum) AS jaar
        ,iif(rating IS NULL, 'Geen rating', iif(rating <= 3, 'Zwaar onvoldoende', iif(rating <= 5, 'Onvoldoende', iif(rating < 8, 'Voldoende', 'Zeer goed')))) AS Klasse
    FROM boeking b
    ) AS b
GROUP BY klasse
```

now if execute this query with out the format it gives the correct numbers without the % symbol. but the format gives the error thats in the title

Comment: Sample data and your desired result will be very very helpful.

Comment: The first param you're passing into FORMAT is `klasse`, but it should be the number that you want to format.  See the syntax for FORMAT( ) function here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what you're doing. Your percentage will always return 100. klasse should be outside of format. You don't use your jaar column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand what you're trying to do, I believe that this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT klasse, format( count(klasse)*1. / (SELECT count(*)FROM boeking), 'p')
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 'Geen rating'
                WHEN rating <= 3 THEN 'Zwaar onvoldoende'
                WHEN rating <= 5 THEN 'Onvoldoende'
                WHEN rating < 8 THEN 'Voldoende'
                ELSE 'Zeer goed' END AS Klasse
    FROM boeking b
    ) AS b
GROUP BY klasse
```

I must leave a very important note. FORMAT will make this query so much slower than formatting it on the front end. If formatting needs to occur here (neglecting the future use of the column as a number) the following can be used.

```
SELECT klasse, CAST( CAST( count(klasse)*100. / (SELECT count(*)FROM boeking) AS decimal(10,2)) AS varchar(13)) + '%'
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 'Geen rating'
                WHEN rating <= 3 THEN 'Zwaar onvoldoende'
                WHEN rating <= 5 THEN 'Onvoldoende'
                WHEN rating < 8 THEN 'Voldoende'
                ELSE 'Zeer goed' END AS Klasse
    FROM boeking b
    ) AS b
GROUP BY klasse
```